# C: How to store int values derived from a while loop in an array, so I can add the digits of those integers later?

Tags: arrays, c, while-loop, integer, cs50

I'm trying to solve this cs50 problem Credit. I'm a beginner to all of this so i'm trying to break down this problem into little parts. Right now I cant figure out how to store in an array the product int values i derived from a while loop. I want to access these values later so i can add the digits of the product in values. Thank you for helping! This is the code i have written so far

```
// Prompt for input
long number = get_long("Card Number: \n");
// initialize number to two different variables for
// [1. multiplying by 2, adding the products] [2. adding every other digit]
long number2 = number;
long number3 = number;

//-----Calculate checksum-----

// Counting the digits
int count = get_number_digits(number);
// Multiply digits by 2 alternately starting from the tens place,
// then add the digit of the products
int firststep, remainderr2, currentnumber2, product;
currentnumber2 = number;
thirdstep = 0;
while(number3 > 0) {
  number3 = currentnumber2;
  currentnumber2 = currentnumber2 / 10;
  remainderr2 = currentnumber2 % 10;
  product = 2 * remainderr2;
  //Storing the products into an array to add them later
  int i, productvalues[i];
  for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    // some code 
  }
}
```

Comment: Start with removing *undefined behavior* `int i; int productvalues[i];` (usage of indeterminate value of uninitialized variable).

Comment: //Storing the products into an array to add them later
        int i = 0;
        int productvalues[i];
        for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            productvalues[i] = product;
        }

Comment: i tried to initialize it then typed this inside the bracket of the for loop. can this store the values?

Comment: (a) You do not need to remember the digits. The task required by this project can be performed by processing the digits during the loop. (b) If you do want to remember the digits, you can create an array. This is possible because the maximum number of digits is known (and you can enforce that limit by rejecting any input with too many digits), so you can create an array with one element for each potential digit. The syntax for declaring such an array is to use a number for the size, not a variable: `int digits[16];`, not `int productvalues[i];`. The array should be created before the loop.